# 'Avoir les boules': submissive or aggressive

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, langage-informel

I just learned the other day ([from Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-les-boules.php)) about the phrase:

> avoir les boules.

They gave its meaning as "Être très énervé. En avoir assez. Avoir peur.". As in,

> Le cartel a les boules car ils ont perdu le respect.

However, the French sounds so similar to a the word-for-word translation which is 'to have the balls'. In English this means 'to have the audacity, to be brave', where 'balls' is being used as slang for testicles, presumably a sign of masculinity.

> You don't have the balls to fight that bully.

[Reverso translates from English to French](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/Do+you+have+the+balls):

> Do you have the balls?

to

> Tu as les balles ?

(notice 'balles' but not 'boules').

Since I am an American English speaker, I am used to the 'balls = courage' metaphor, but I don't see the metaphor in French. Is 'les boules' slang for something else (other than testicles) or is it referring to gonads (to be clinical about it) by a different metaphor that yields something less aggressive, or have I mistranslated a false friend?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't confuse *[avoir les boules](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/avoir-les-boules.php)* (because of sth) and *[avoir les couilles](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/avoir%20les%20couilles%20de)* (to do sth).

The latter matches *to have the balls / the guts*.

In the former one, the *boules* are more the *glandes* (the expression *[avoir les glandes](http://www.expressions-francaises.fr/expressions-a/1697-avoir-les-glandes.html)* exists too).

Despite being originally the same balls we were referring to earlier, these *glandes/boules* are generally understood nowadays to be the ganglia or the tonsils (on each top sides of the neck).

Someone who ***a les boules*** is annoyed, upset, worried, scared, frustrated because of something unpleasant has happened or is feared.

On the other hand <sub><sup>([no pun intended](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cela_m%E2%80%99en_touche_une_sans_faire_bouger_l%E2%80%99autre) ;-) )</sup></sub>, Reverso translation "*tu as les balles ?*" would only make sense on a tennis court, a golf course, or similar ;-)

Comment: Thanks. That last thing you say about 'tu as les balles' is why we ask on SE rather than trust even authoritative translation services or dictionaries.

Comment: ...and watch out, in Canadian French,  *les boules* as a body part mean "boobs", not "balls" !

Comment: @Greg not to mention the *gosses* ;-)

Comment: One also often makes a gripping move on the neck to show that they really *ont les boules*

Comment: Re: comments on those, see Canada/Quebec entries for [_boule_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/boule), [_gosse_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gosse#Nom_commun_2), [_plotte_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plotte) which may prove [challenging](https://www.ledevoir.com/monde/europe/231677/un-ecart-de-langage-qui-intrigue) indeed...

Comment: I would also add *a bit scared* to the list of meanings (*j'ai rendu mon contrôle mais j'ai les boules* (j'ai peur d'avoir raté)). Excellent answer BTW (+1)

Comment: Nice all. Thanks for the extra nuances @Greg, WoJ, Jardin.

Comment: @Mitch You're welcome!