# « Ça m'enrage » est-il un régionalisme québécois etc. ?

Tags: québec, locutions, régionalismes, lexique

Une candidate à l'immigration au Québec, victime des politiques [dilogiques](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26542617) de l'[immigrant jetable](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/chroniques/rima-elkouri/201902/14/01-5214819-limmigrant-jetable-bis.php) de la province dominée par la [droite](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-quebecoise/201611/12/01-5040632-francois-legault-a-laise-detre-compare-a-trump.php) (et non le *centre droit* comme le mentionne l'AFP), [déclare](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/politique-quebecoise/201902/15/01-5214900-au-quebec-la-colere-de-milliers-de-candidats-a-limmigration.php) :

> Ça me donne la [rage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rage).

On parle de l'« état affectif [...] qui est généralement causé par un sentiment d'impuissance devant une situation frustrante » (TLFi ; « L'immense bêtise moderne me donne la rage. », Flaubert) et non de la maladie infectieuse. Ça peut sembler évident mais je ne connais pas cet emploi ; je connais uniquement *ça m'[enrage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enrage)* (« J'avais gardé mon sang-froid, mais tant de misères m'enragent ! », [Borel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9trus_Borel) au TLFi) ou peut-être *ça me fait [rager](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rage/1)/enrager* et dans le premier cas (*m'enrage*) je remarque que le dictionnaire de mon fureteur ne semble pas le reconnaître...

---

- Ailleurs qu'au Québec, emploie-t-on *ça/telle chose m'enrage* ; est-ce
  un régionalisme propre au Québec uniquement ?
- Peut-on classer par fréquence d'emploi ou selon ce qui est le plus
  courant d'après son expérience, dans le sens de mettre en colère : *ça m'enrage*, *ça me donne la rage*, *ça me fait rager*, *ça me fait enrager*, *ça me met en rage* ?

Comment: Tiens moi je dis « ça me fait enrager » et je ne savais pas qu'il y avait autant de variations.

Comment: [*Ça me fout les boules.*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33809/avoir-les-boules-submissive-or-aggressive)

Answer (score 1):

Oui cette expression est également utilisée en dehors du Québec, notamment en France métropolitaine, [source.](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/%C3%A7a+m%27enrage.html)

Comme par exemple dans la phrase suivante:

> Chaque fois que je vois la petite maudite cassette pour me donner en français les
> mesures de sécurité, cela m'enrage.

La signification la plus proche pourrait être la suivante:

> **Cela m'énerve.** qui signifie être furieux, en colère.
>
> Synonymes : manifester, [rager](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/rager/)

Concernant le classement par fréquence d'emploi j'aurais fais comme ci-dessous *(note: ceci est un avis [subjectif](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/subjectif/) basé sur mon vécu)*:

- ça m'enrage.
- ça me fait rager.
- ça me donne la rage.
- ça me fait enrager.
- ça me met en rage.

Comment: Cela dit, étant donné la propension à utiliser un langage direct, courant, voire familier ou grossier sous le coup de la colère, il est vraisemblable qu'une grande partie des personnes susceptibles d'utiliser de telles expressions en situation soit de la génération d'avant-guerre.

Comment: @RomainValeri Je ne sais pas, ce n'est sans doute pas le cas de cette candidate à l'immigration dont je parlais, probablement une étudiante... autrement on peut faire précéder d'un juron... _christ que ça m'enrage_... Par ailleurs je vous assure que je ne suis pas de la génération dont vous parlez..., même pas de celle d'avant le Vietnam ;-)

Comment: @Jardindefrostedflakes Oui c'est bien ce que je pressentais : l'expression (comme un certain nombre d'autres) sonne nettement plus "vieillie" en France qu'au Québec.

Comment: Merci, j'espère qu'on aura éventuellement d'autres réponses pour comparer...